# Custom HTTP Response Header for Refreshing Claims

Tags: http-headers

**Problem Statement**

A client `Foo` sends HTTP requests to an API `Bar`.
`Bar` provides a special endpoint `Baz` for `Foo` to call whenever `Bar` tells it to. `Baz` is an endpoint to refresh the user's claims. By design, these are very special claims not meant to be transported in a JSON Web Token.

**Proposed Solution**

A possible solution is to have a custom response header `X-Baz` with a boolean value. `Foo` checks every HTTP response for `X-Baz: true` to call `Baz` right after.

**Question**

Does that approach have any disadvantages apart from its synchronous nature? I'm aware of custom *request* headers to have difficulties to pass certain reverse-proxy settings. Is there a similar problem with proxies filtering or blocking *responses* with custom headers?

**Notes**

Even though it is not recommended anymore to use the `X-` prefix for custom headers, I used it here to emphasise the custom nature of this header.

A real-time feedback, such as with `SignalR`, is definitely a good solution. It enables `Bar` to immediately tell `Foo` to call `Baz`. This type of technology is already under consideration, I'm merely looking for simpler solutions.